# Using Clang and LLVM

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++, llc

I am compiling this:

```
int main(){
}
```

With clang, using this command line:

```
clang++.exe -S -o %OUTFILE%.clang -emit-llvm %INFILE% -I. -I%INCLUDE_PATH% -std=c++14 -ftemplate-depth=1000
```

Which gives me llvm byte-code.

Then I use `llc` like so, to convert the byte-code into c code:

```
llc "%IN_FILE%.clang" -march=c -o foo.c
```

And get this error:

```
error: unterminated attribute group
attributes #0 = { norecurse nounwind uwtable "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
```

What I am doing wrong?

This is what clang++ is giving me:

```
; ModuleID = 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\C++\SVN\prototypeInd\util\StaticBigInt.cpp'
target datalayout = "e-m:w-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc18.0.0"

; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 0
}

attributes #0 = { norecurse nounwind readnone uwtable "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!1 = !{!"clang version 3.8.0 (branches/release_38)"}
```

**Note:**
I am using `clang` version 3.8 and `llc` version 3.4

Comment: It looks like a version incompatibility between `clang` and `llc`. Can you post an entire "%IN_FILE%.clang"?

Comment: @deniss Sure...one moment

Comment: Your code compiles fine with up to date `llc` version, except that [c backend was removed in 3.1](http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#whatsnew)

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command such as:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm ...
```

Then the compiler emits not an IR in a bitcode form, but human readable representation.

It makes sense if all tools you use have the same versions, or if you just want to inspect the output manually.

However, the human readable IR may be incompatible with old tools.

In this case I can recommend to use bitcode directly (note that there is no `-S` parameter anymore):

```
clang -emit-llvm
```

Comment: "no -S parameter anymore" ... Since what version?

Comment: Since we don't need human readable IR. It's no about versions. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Even in bitcode form, IR is not backward compatible.

Comment: @MichaelHaidl that is correct. However, it may work in situations when human readable version doesn't work. It happened for me once or twice - switching to bitcode was the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

C backend in LLVM was removed several years ago. It seems that you're trying to feed LLVM IR from the recent LLVM version to llc from old LLVM. This is certainly not supported - the IR is not compatible between the versions.